# Optaplanner integration

Tags: java, maven, spring-data-jpa, optaplanner

I am trying to integrate OptaPlanner in my project. I am working with Spring jpa, maven and mysql database.
I have implemented the dependencies on my maven file, so I can use the annotations of OptaPlanner, but I don't know how to use it. I have been reading the documentation and examples but i still don't know how to use it.

I have to assign recipes and an user to a class called FoodList. Each object of FoodList has id, 2 enums, the recipe, the user and a Date, i show:

- FoodList class:

```
@PlanningEntity()
@Entity
public class ListaComida {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Comida comida;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Plato plato;
    @PlanningVariable()
    @ManyToOne
    private Receta receta;
    @PlanningVariable()
    @ManyToOne
    private Usuario usuario;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDate fecha;
...
}
```

```
@PlanningSolution // OptaPlanner annotation
@TypeDef(defaultForType = HardSoftScore.class, typeClass = HardSoftScoreHibernateType.class) // Hibernate annotation
public class ListaComidaSolution {

    @Columns(columns = {@Column(name = "hardScore"), @Column(name = "softScore")})
    private HardSoftScore score;

    @PlanningScore
    public HardSoftScore getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(HardSoftScore score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

```
<!-- Score configuration -->
<scoreDirectorFactory>
    <easyScoreCalculatorClass>src/main/java/es.uca.AutomaticFoodList/GenerarComidaEasyScoreCalculator</easyScoreCalculatorClass>
    <!--<scoreDrl>org/optaplanner/examples/cloudbalancing/solver/cloudBalancingScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>-->
</scoreDirectorFactory>

<!-- Optimization algorithms configuration -->
<termination>
    <secondsSpentLimit>30</secondsSpentLimit>
</termination>
```

```
public class GenerarComidaEasyScoreCalculator implements EasyScoreCalculator<ListaComidaSolution> {
    public HardSoftScore calculateScore(ListaComidaSolution listaComidaSolution){
        int hardScore = 0, softScore = 0;
        return HardSoftScore.of(hardScore, softScore);
    }
}
```

- This class is not implemented, but I think I have to do it.

```
public static void generarListaComida(){
        //SolverFactory<CloudBalance> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(
        //        "org/optaplanner/examples/cloudbalancing/solver/cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml");
        //Solver<CloudBalance> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();

        // Load a problem with 400 computers and 1200 processes
        //CloudBalance unsolvedCloudBalance = new CloudBalancingGenerator().createCloudBalance(400, 1200);

        // Solve the problem
        //CloudBalance solvedCloudBalance = solver.solve(unsolvedCloudBalance);

        // Display the result
        //System.out.println("\nSolved cloudBalance with 400 computers and 1200 processes:\n"
        //        + toDisplayString(solvedCloudBalance));
    }
```

Is this all classes and files I need to implement this in my project?, or I have to implement more classes?

Comment: On Stackoverflow, you need to ask _specific_ questions.

Comment: I have edited my question, i hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

On https://www.optaplanner.org/ you can download an executable demo. However it is not just an executable demo but also contains the source code of the examples ( in `examples/source` folder). There you can see how optaplanner is used in the example applications, and you can do the same in your application.

A good starting point is also https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.36.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#plannerConfiguration chapter 4 ff.

Comment: See also the spring-boot optaplanner example: https://github.com/ge0ffrey/getting-started-guides/tree/gs-constraint-solving-ai-optaplanner/complete

Comment: Okay, I am going to revise your links. Thank you.